# Get a particlular div content using PHP

Tags: php

I am getting a page content(not cross domain) using curl. It works fine. The page content contains header footer everything.

Now inside that page content there is a div with id called "**pickupme**". I want to extract the html within that div id "pickmeup".

My code is

```
$caseStudyhtml = $this->getHTML(BASE_URL);

preg_match("/<div id=\"pickup\">(.*?)<\/div>/s", $caseStudyhtml, $match);
```

The full html which stores in caseStudyhtml  is fine. But I think for some reason the preg_match rule is not perfect.

Comment: Sir I am using preg_match and really don't wanna use dom :)

Comment: You should really try to use DOM instead.

Comment: I think I have to because if the content is too long then there might be some data loss.